# String manipulation in Customer Order Email body

Tags: magento2.4

In Magento 2.4, I have a need to process both shipping and bliling addresses before sending the email alert to the customer. Basically I need to do a regex replace of addresses. It should be applicable only to emails while address saved in db remains unchanged.

I tried with a plugin, it didnt work. Also could not find a matching observer event.

Can someone please let me know the proper path.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: which plugin you tried ?